# Prevent WinRT App from entering suspend state in a Line-of-Business app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, line-of-business-app

I'm developing a line of business app for Windows 8.1, that is, I am not deploying through the Windows Store and will be able to control all of the features of both the OS and hardware this app is being deployed on.

Because this app is working as the UI in a real-time situation I would prefer if I could ignore the life-cycle events and not have the app suspend or terminate at the whim of Windows 8.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I have seen some older answers, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627947/how-to-disable-suspending-closing-terminating-event-for-my-metro-style-app) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819882/can-developers-force-the-system-to-prevent-metro-apps-from-being-suspended-w) indicating otherwise, but I haven't yet found anything more recently and specifically dealing with the case of a line of business app.  I have found the [Embedded Lockdown Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=37020) which would prevent the app losing focus and addresses some of the needs I have, but I still would like a way to simple disable Lifecycle events.

Comment: "When put into debug mode, an app will not be subject to termination and **will not be automatically suspended**": http://stackoverflow.com/a/19459956/1466046

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Assigned Access Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/assigned-access?woldogcb=0)? Basically use PC Settings -> Accounts to lock an account to a single app. You have to reboot the device and log-in again in order to run anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I did check that out and while it would be useful for locking down the computer ideally it would be good if I could occasionally minimize the app and still have it run in the background.