# ViewManagement.FullScreenSystemOverlayMode and taskbar visibility

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I am developing Windows 10 Universal App using C#. My question is refers to a case when an user runs my application on PC/desktop.

I want my app to be full screen, this can by done by calling

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement::TryEnterFullScreenMode()
```

Now we are in full screen. But when user swipes mouse pointer to lower edge of the screen Windows' Taskbar will appear and I don't want it to appear - what can I do?

I've tried setting `FullScreenSystemOverlayMode` property of corresponding `Windows.UI.ViewManagement` to `FullScreenSystemOverlayMode`.

Minimal alongside with setting `SuppressSystemOverlays` to `true`.

Neither has helped, what can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to get into a "Kiosk mode" where the user can never get out of your app? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484964/prevent-winrt-app-from-entering-suspend-state-in-a-line-of-business-app/30497861#30497861

Answer (score 2):

When I do something like that I use:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SuppressSystemOverlays = true;
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().FullScreenSystemOverlayMode = FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal;
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

Maybe just semantics, but sometime those semantics matter.

Comment: From what I see, your piece of code has excactly the same effect as         bare ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode(); . Try to move mouse cursor to the bottom edge of the screen and taskbar will show up - the issue is that I don't want to see this taskbar

Comment: As far as I can tell this comment is as close to correct as you can get.  It does not appear to be possible to totally disable the taskbar and Action center.  Setting FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal before entering fullscreen mode will replace the taskbar and action center swipe actions with a small UI handle that can be dragged to open the respective UI's.  I verified this myself.  SuppressSystemOverlays is deprecated according to the docs on MSDN.